# Permissions error in WordPress site using move_uploaded_file on theme directory

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a site in which I'm getting the following error when trying to use move_uploaded_file operation (see below)...

I also notice that when I attempt to delete a theme, WordPress asks me for my FTP credentials. I believe these issues are connected. Do you agree?

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(/home2/mySite/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/myUpgrader.zip)
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed
>   to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home2/mySite/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/upload.php
>   on line 79
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file()
>   [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable
>   to move '/tmp/phpEva1Tw' to
>   '/home2/mySite/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/myUpgrader.zip'
>   in
>   /home2/mySite/public_html/wp-content/themes/myTheme/upload.php
>   on line 79 There was a problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I would say you lack permission necessary to write in the folder you are trying to upload those files or the owner of the folders is different by the owner running the PHP.

You can take a look here: http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2003/02/20/php_foundations.html

Or search for chown, chmod and maybe connect to your site with ftp and verify the CHMOD levels and who he owner is.